# How do I do this sql select query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
+----+-----------+-----+
| p1 | p2 | model| res |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 | a  | dog  |  1  |
|  2 | a  | dog  |  2  |
|  1 | b  | dog  |  3  |
|  2 | b  | dog  |  4  |
|  1 | a  | cat  |  10 |
|  2 | a  | cat  |  2  |
|  1 | b  | cat  |  10 |
|  2 | b  | cat  |  1  |
+----+-----------+-----+
```

What I want, is for each combination of p1 and p2, select the one that gets the lowest sum for res over for all models).
The sum scores in this case are:

```
p1=1, p2=a: 1+10=11
p1=2, p2=a: 2+2=4
p1=1, p2=b: 3+10=13
p1=2, p2=b: 4+1=5
```

So I would like to get the following table:

```
+----+-----------+-----+
| p1 | p2 | model| res |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  2 | a  | dog  |  2  |
|  2 | a  | cat  |  2  |
+----+-----------+-----+
```

Note: There may be more p columns (i.e p3, p4,...)

What sql select query should I use in order to get the desired table above?

Comment: What database engine do you use? And what have you already tried?

Comment: I use sqlite. I have tried group by, but it doesn't do what I want. My question is: "What sql select query should I use in order to get the desired resulting table?"

Comment: **Show us what you have tried, and explain how it didn't do what you wanted.**  It's not enough to say "I tried X, and it didn't work."  Show us *exactly* what you tried, and then explain *exactly* how it didn't work.  Otherwise, you're just asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: I tried "select * from TEST group by p1", but I saw it's really not what I need, simply due to counting considerations (the number of rows I need are like DISTINCT model, and group by p1 and/or p2 would return something unrelated to that. Since I knew my approach was fundamentally flawed,I didn't want to waste anyone's time reading it.

Comment: Anyone have a better name for this question so that others can find it more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/af26b/5

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TEST t1
JOIN (
  SELECT p1, p2
  FROM TEST
  GROUP BY p1, p2
  ORDER BY SUM(res)
  LIMIT 1) t2 ON t1.p1 = t2.p1 AND t1.p2 = t2.p2
```

Comment: That's really awesome, both your solution and that sqlfiddle link you gave. I didn't know about the LIMIT command. I'll read up on it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
select * from the_table
group by model          # do it for each distinct model
order by res ascending  # to get the lower ones first so that limit can pick them
limit 1                 # for each group, i think it will do that.
```